# Pango and FreeType -- not rendering text, just weird pixels

Tags: c, freetype, pango

I'm trying to get Pango to control FreeType. I've successfully got FreeType to render into a bitmap but Pango doesn't seem to know what's going on, I'm obviously not doing something correctly.

This is the code that I'm using at the moment:

```
font_map = pango_ft2_font_map_new();
pango_ft2_font_map_set_resolution(PANGO_FT2_FONT_MAP(font_map), 72, 72);
cr = pango_font_map_create_context(PANGO_FONT_MAP(font_map));

font_description = pango_font_description_new ();
pango_font_description_set_family (font_description, "Courier New");
pango_font_description_set_weight (font_description, PANGO_WEIGHT_BOLD);
pango_font_description_set_absolute_size (font_description, 32 * PANGO_SCALE);

layout = pango_layout_new(cr);
pango_layout_set_font_description(layout, font_description);
pango_layout_set_text(layout, "Some sample text!", -1);

pango_context_set_font_description(cr, font_description);

FT_Bitmap bitmap = { 0 };
bitmap.width = drawBitmap.get()->getWidth();
bitmap.rows = drawBitmap.get()->getHeight();
bitmap.pitch = bitmap.width * 4;
bitmap.buffer = (unsigned char*)drawBitmap.get()->getDataPtr();
bitmap.num_grays = 256;
bitmap.pixel_mode = FT_PIXEL_MODE_GRAY;
pango_ft2_render_layout(&bitmap, layout, 100, 100);
```

`drawBitmap` is just my helper class, I know this works because I can fill it with random colours and they show up.

This is what gets rendered:

[image]

I want to try to get that text to show up properly.

---

EDIT: The problem has been brought into sharper relief after fixing the bit depth of the image and switching from bare Pango FreeType to Pango Cairo with the FreeType engine.

Using this line:

```
font_map = pango_cairo_font_map_new_for_font_type(CAIRO_FONT_TYPE_WIN32);
```

produces

[image]

and when I run through `pango_font_map_list_families`, I get a long list of the fonts installed on my system.

However if I change it to this, to use FreeType:

```
font_map = pango_cairo_font_map_new_for_font_type(CAIRO_FONT_TYPE_FT);
```

it produces

[image]

and then there are suddenly only 3 fonts on my system, `Sans`, `Serif` and `Monospace`.

Comment: I don't know if this is related but `pango_font_map_list_families` is only listing `Sans`, `Serif` and `Monospace` as available fonts so I wonder if Pango is understanding Windows' font structure...

Comment: (1) Could this be the default "Not Available" characters being drawn? In lots of fonts it is a simple rectangle such as this. (2) Zooming in, there seems to be some RGB overlapping. Are you correctly converting from grayscale (what FreeType returns) to RGb (apparently, your output format)?

Comment: @Jongware: You are right on both fronts, I've fixed the RGB/grayscale confusion and they now show as regular white boxes. The next step is to figure out why they are not rendering as actual text.

Answer (score 2):

I just hit exactly the same issue as yourself but after a lot of digging managed to find a solution that works for me. I've been using the pre-built Pango/FreeType/dependencies libraries from http://www.gtk.org/download/win32.php and copying the runtime DLLs to my exe folder. In the end I had to also copy the '/etc/fonts' folder from the all-in-one version of GTK+ as a subfolder of my exe too. Then suddenly I had fonts via Pango/FreeType! Not sure what the origin of the 'fonts' folder is yet though..

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to tell it where your font files are located manually, freetype alone has no notion of default font locations it's a barebones renderer (and it is really insufficient to display unicode text, that's why other pango engines add other libraries to the mix)

pango-cairo is the most complete pango backend IIRC, and unless I'm wrong it will pull in fontconfig. fontconfig sole purpose is to manage font file locations for apps, that's why it's working out of the box for you

If your chosen backend does use fontconfig try to locate its master conf file and make sure the default directories are appropriate for your system. And then run fc-cache